# Cartesian Impedance control Damping Design (Double Diagonalization)

Tags: control, robotic-arm, dynamics, manipulator, theory

In the literature, it is often seen that for a system:

\begin{align}
        \Lambda \ddot{e} + D_d \dot{e} + K_d e = F_{ext}
\end{align}

A dynamic damping matrix is required for a robot to take into account the structure and changes of $\Lambda$ during movement. Hence the following method called the "double diagonalization".

Given a symmetric and positive definite matrix $\Lambda \in \mathcal{R}^{n\times n}$ and a symmetric matrix $K_d \in \mathcal{R}^{n\times n}$, one can find a non singular matrix $Q \in \mathcal{R}^{n\times n}$ and a diagonal matrix $B_0 \in \mathcal{R}^{n\times n}$ such that:
\begin{align}
    \Lambda &= Q^\intercal Q\\
    K_d &= Q^\intercal B_0 Q
\end{align}
Where the diagonal elements of $B_0$ are the generalized eigenvalues of $K_d$

The design of the damping matrix becomes:
\begin{align}
    D_d = 2 Q^\intercal diag( \xi \sqrt(\lambda_{K,i}^\Lambda) Q)
\end{align}

Such that
\begin{align}
    Q^\intercal Q \ddot{x} + 2 Q^\intercal diag( \xi \sqrt(\lambda_{K,i}^\Lambda) Q) \dot{x} + Q^\intercal B_0 Q x = F_{ext}
\end{align}

where $\xi_i$ is the damping factor in the range of $[0,1]$, $\lambda_{K,i}^\Lambda$ is the i'th diagonal element of $B_0$

-
Yeah, I 'm pretty dumb (I'm guessing the solution is simple but I cannot see it). I cannot figure out how to solve for the matrices $Q$ and $B_0$, such that (in particular) $\Lambda = Q^\intercal Q$. What am I missing? Can elaborate for me?

**How do I solve this?**

Sources: (this article should be free and provide some context.)
[(Albu-Schaffer, Alin, et al., 2003)](http://www.informatik.uni-bremen.de/agebv2/downloads/published/albuschaeffericra03.pdf)

Comment: Great question! I've bookmarked this because I've had unsatisfactory results with a vanilla state feedback controller and I'm about to embark on my own impedance control project. I always find it particularly infuriating when papers skip major steps; they'll typically work through some derivation to a point, skip the important implementation steps, and then jump straight into some results figures. Anyways, good luck with the question, I'll be watching for answers!

Comment: @Chuck Yeah, I very much relate to that - that's precisely how I felt about this topic. And thanks for the encouragement :)! a bit late, now that someone has answered the question. but thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A hint towards what the answer is given in the paper. Namely, one can use the [generalized eigenvalue decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Generalized_eigenvalue_problem), which in this case can be formulated as finding eigenvalues $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and eigenvectors $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that

$$
(\lambda\,\Lambda - K_d)\,v = 0. \tag{1}
$$

Consider two distinct solutions $(\lambda_i,v_i)$ and $(\lambda_j,v_j)$ of $(1)$, which can also be written as

\begin{align}
\lambda_i\,\Lambda\,v_i &= K_d\,v_i, \tag{2a} \\
\lambda_j\,\Lambda\,v_j &= K_d\,v_j. \tag{2b}
\end{align}

By pre-multiplying $(2a)$ by $v_j^\top$ and $(2b)$ by $v_i^\top$ one gets

\begin{align}
\lambda_i\,v_j^\top \Lambda\,v_i &= v_j^\top K_d\,v_i, \tag{3a} \\
\lambda_j\,v_i^\top \Lambda\,v_j &= v_i^\top K_d\,v_j. \tag{3b}
\end{align}

When using that $M = M^\top$ and $K_d = K_d^\top$ it follows that when subtracting the transpose of $(3b)$ from $(3a)$ one gets

$$
(\lambda_i - \lambda_j)\,v_j^\top \Lambda\,v_i = 0. \tag{4}
$$

Thus when $\lambda_i \neq \lambda_j$ it follows that $v_j^\top \Lambda\,v_i = 0$, from which together with $(3a)$ it also follows that $v_j^\top K_d\,v_i = 0$. When $i \neq j$ but $\lambda_i = \lambda_j$ this orthogonality property between vectors $v_i$ and $v_j$, and matrices $\Lambda$ and $K_d$ does not immediately follow. It can be noted that $\lambda_i = \lambda_j = \lambda$ means that the kernel of $\lambda\,\Lambda - K_d$ has a dimension larger then one, such that for all $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ the vector $v = \alpha\,v_i + \beta\,v_j$ would satisfy $(1)$. However, most generalized eigenvalue problem solvers "choose" $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that they do ensure that $v_j^\top \Lambda\,v_i = 0$ and $v_j^\top K_d\,v_i = 0$ whenever $\lambda_i = \lambda_j$.

When defining $V$ as the matrix whose columns are equal to $v_i\ \forall\,i=1,2,\cdots, n$ it follows from $v_j^\top \Lambda\,v_i = v_j^\top K_d\,v_i = 0$ that $V^\top \Lambda\,V$ and $V^\top K_d\,V$ are diagonal matrices. By also dividing each $i$th column of $V$ by $\sqrt{v_i^\top \Lambda\,v_i}$ one also obtains that $V^\top \Lambda\,V = I$ and $V^\top K_d\,V = \text{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_n)$. Solving this for $\Lambda$ and $K_d$ yields

\begin{align}
\Lambda &= V^{-\top} V^{-1}, \tag{5a} \\
K_d &= V^{-\top} \text{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_n)\,V^{-1}, \tag{5b}
\end{align}

which is equivalent to using $Q = V^{-1}$ and $B_0 = \text{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_n)$.

For more information of this derivation see section 3.3.2 from the book De Kraker, A. (2009). Mechanical vibrations. Shaker Publishing BV.

Comment: I love you, man.